# How to encrypt/decrypt a session value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-blade

In my login controller I am creating a session with the value of email that user used to log in. From there I am using that session in different pages including home,profile and other pages. 
The issue is I dont want to store the raw email in session so anyone can read this using burpsuite or other tools, so I am decrypting the value of email before storing it in session. Now I dont know how can I get back the decrypted value on other pages. Below is the code.

//LoginController

```
 $email=encrypt($request->emailOrNumber);
 \Session::put('email',$email);
```

Now If I am trying to get this value using the below code in my blade view I am getting the encrypted value. How Can I get back the decrypted value of email? Need your suggestions. Thanks

```
{{Session::get('email')}}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption

Comment: I tried to use the decrypt function but that is not working, Since I am encrypting the value and getting the value from key.

Comment: Can you provide an exemple how do you try to decrypt as well?

Comment: @cbaconnier using this code in blade file. {{ Session::get decrypt( ('email') ) }}

Comment: Try this instead `decrypt(Session::get('email'));` You're trying to decrypt the key `email` instead of the value returned by the session

Comment: thats worked. Thanks <3

Comment: No problem! I posted it as answer so you can validate and close your question :)

Comment: @cbaconnier done buddy <3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment

To decrypt the email use `decrypt()` to decrypt the value returned by the session.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/encryption

```php
decrypt(Session::get('email'));
```